# result from string array to textview when button clicked

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

https://s8.postimg.cc/nryfeo8xh/Screenshot_8.png

i have some code that has to add a string result from an array to a textView when a button is clicked.

it has 3 components
textView
editText
button

there's an array with results that when the button is clicked has to be added on the textView with the editText on top of the array random result

1. 1st try

   - editText = hi there
   - click button
   - textview=
   - hi there
   - three (from array random result)
2. 2nd try

   - editText = hi again
   - click button
   - textview=
   - hi again
   - two
   - hi there (previous result)
   - three (previous result)

text view is almost a log file

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System;

namespace APP
{

    [Activity(Label = "APP", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        string[] constStringArray = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };


        TextView res;
        EditText edt;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            edt = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
            res = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
            Button btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);

            btn.Click += Btn_Click;

        }

        private void Btn_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

            string constStringArray = res.Text.ToString();

            res.Text = constStringArray;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A screenshot might be helpful, I can't really understand what you mean

Comment: here's a screenshot https://s8.postimg.cc/nryfeo8xh/Screenshot_8.png

Comment: i dont see the code where you update the `TextView`? Am I missing something? You only set it to the already value. `res.Text = res.Text;`